# Does the "with" keyword (or default method) exist in java?

Tags: java, keyword

I'm working on a code when I notice the following "with" keyword on the constructor and I wanted to know what kind of constructor (or technique) is this, and how to use it.

```
public static Database with(String key) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new Database(key);
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

And one usage of this is:

```
mDatabase = Database.with(User.listAll(User.class).get(0).getKey());
```

Comment: That's not a keyword, just an ordinary method.

Comment: It's just a method that accepts a `String` and returns a `Database`.

Comment: If anything, it's a rephrasing of the singleton design pattern with naming chosen to create a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a constructor, it's a static method which (I presume) returns an instance of the class in which it's contained

Answer (score 1):

The `with` here is not a keyword, it's just the name of a static method.